# ListTile's background color visible outside of ListView

Tags: flutter, listview

I am creating a notes app.In my application I have a search Box and Title above  the listview.

when I scroll the listtiles are visible below serch box  (Text and icons aren't but the background color is visible).
how can i avoid this?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
        child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
              Text(
                "this is title",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
              ),
              Spacer(
                flex: 1,
              ),
              TextField(
                decoration:
                    InputDecoration(fillColor: Colors.green, filled: true),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              Expanded(
                  flex: 6,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: 19,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return ListTile(
                          title: Text("some text"),
                          tileColor: Colors.blue[200],
                        );
                      }))
            ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a very strange error. As the ListView prebuilds the closest views, it becomes visible as there is no first layer to hide behind. I fixed it by replacing the first `Padding` widget with a `Container` and assigning a background color. From there, the background color of the tiles stopped working. This was fixed by answer on the following post: [ListTile's SelectedTileColor is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71293162/listtiles-selectedtilecolor-is-not-working)

Here is the working code

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
        child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
              Text(
                "this is title",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
              ),
              Spacer(
                flex: 1,
              ),
              TextField(
                decoration:
                    InputDecoration(fillColor: Colors.green, filled: true),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              Expanded(
                  flex: 6,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: 19,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Material(
                          type: MaterialType.transparency,
                          child: ListTile(
                            title: Text("some text"),
                            tileColor: Colors.blue[200],
                          ),
                        );
                      }))
            ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```